# Netbeans Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, debian, debian-stretch

My computer operating system is Linux-Debian 9 (stretch) and I'm running Netbeans 8.2 When I want to run any JavaFX project on Netbeans it shows following error ...
"Netbeans Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle."
I'm getting this error when I run my project first time after modifying the code.If I rerun again the project, there is no error.
Why I'm getting this error and how to fix this?
Thank you.

Console output..

`ant -f "/home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI" jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: /home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/build/classes
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Internal error. Missing resources [/resources/web-files/javafx-loading-100x100.gif]
JNLP failed : Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution
com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerException: Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.jnlp.JNLPBundler.execute(JNLPBundler.java:493)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:318)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$53$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:405)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:109)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:53)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
/home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1487: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3134: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/niloy/NetBeansProjects/Bank Account UI/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:2096: Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)`

Comment: Please provide the console output

Comment: console output provided. Please check the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling „java deployment toolkit not included netbeans“ lists an entry in the Netbeans bug database:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269759
The entry suggests to workaround the problem by setting
javafx.deploy.includeDT to false
in the nbproject/project.properties